# How to import excel spreadsheet into access and cross reference two tables

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have the following two Access tables

```
Employees
id          Name
1           bob smith
2           james bird
3           jane big


Events
id         emp_id        Notes
1          1             fell down the stairs
2          3             paper cut in the break room
```

I also have the following Excel file that I would like to 'suck' (import) into the Events table. The problem is the data needs to be correlated on the name/emp_id field and I'm not sure the best way to do this.

```
Excel_sheet

Employee Name       Notes
bob smith           feel asleep while driving
```

The access table uses references to the Employees table, whereas the Excel sheet is using names. What are some options for me to bring this Excel sheet into Events table and convert the names (bob smith) into their associated id's from the Employees table?

Comment: Any solution depends on names in both data sources having consistent spelling and each name applies to only one person. If there are multiple Bob Smith you are SOL. If worksheet is simple enough, set a link in Access, build query joining datasets on name fields, and run INSERT SELECT action. When you have attempt with specific issue, post question with code. Otherwise, fix the worksheet to add employee ID. This will be a tedious process of reviewing each row and entering the ID.

Comment: ive imported the excel spreadsheet into access as a new table. The question is, how do I turn those names into the emp_id to then do a insert select?

Comment: Already described technique. Doesn't matter if the Excel is linked or imported.

Comment: select employeeName from excel_sheet as emp_id ... i'm not sure here

Answer (score 0):

Assuming names are consistently spelled in both datasets and only one person exists for each name, try:

`INSERT INTO Events(emp_ID, Notes) SELECT ID, Notes FROM excel_sheet INNER JOIN Employees ON Employees.Name=excel_sheet.[Employee Name];`

Build that SQL in a query object or run in VBA:

`CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Events(emp_ID, Notes) " & _
           "SELECT ID, Notes FROM excel_sheet " & _
           "INNER JOIN Employees ON Employees.Name=excel_sheet.[Employee Name];"`

Suggest you test with a copy of database.

Name is a reserved word and really should not use reserved words as names for anything.